# Can we attach multiple images to a useform in VBA, save in a folder with a specific naming convention and retrieve later using that name?

Tags: excel, vba, lookup, attachment, userform

I have a VBA project where I need to create a userform on which there should be an attachment button to select multiple images and save them in a folder with a specific name. Later, if a person looks up that name from the search box, it should call all the information saved along with the images.  The names should be as follows Sh-0001-01 (where 0001 represents invoice number and 01 denotes attachment number).

I have got a file from another forum that can load images into the image box and scroll across them but there is no mechanism to add new images except copying new images to the back-end folder. And also, no functionality to save attachments with a specific name and look them up using that name.

The outcome is attached as an image. The example code file can be accessed via this link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HXLjDIpjNmgxLxegYiexxEykh4f_54sY/view?usp=sharing

As it was mandatory by Stackoverflow to include a sample code, here is part of the code that is in the file in the drive:

```
Public Const fPath As String = "C:\Test\"
Sub LaunchForm()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Function PhotoNum(numx As Integer) As String
Dim PhotoNames As String, iFile As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim ArrayPhoto() As Variant
iFile = "*.*"
PhotoNames = Dir(fPath & iFile) 
i = 0
Do Until PhotoNames = ""
i = i + 1
ReDim Preserve ArrayPhoto(1 To i)
ArrayPhoto(i) = PhotoNames
PhotoNames = Dir
Loop
PhotoNum = ArrayPhoto(numx)

End Function

Function MaxPhoto() As Integer
Dim PhotoNames As String, iFile As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim ArrayPhoto() As Variant 
iFile = "*.*"
PhotoNames = Dir(fPath & iFile)
i = 0
Do Until PhotoNames = ""
i = i + 1
ReDim Preserve ArrayPhoto(1 To i)
ArrayPhoto(i) = PhotoNames
PhotoNames = Dir
Loop

MaxPhoto = UBound(ArrayPhoto)

End Function
```

Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: "Can we..." Probably yes. Have you searched for similar questions on here?

Comment: Your question it  not clear, at least, for me. In the example you show ("Sh-0001-01"), according to your description, we can understand that the invoice number is "Sh-00". Is that true? Then, the last two digits are "01", exactly as ones after "Sh-00". The example is  not so eloquent, so at which of then do you refer? Since in the picture you show "Sh-0002" as "Invoice number", what should we understand from the above mentioned issues point of view? Are there the last two digits mentioned somewhere on the form an I am missing them? Why don't you simple describe the needed process **in words**?

Comment: @FaneDuru the starting number should be invoice number "Sh-0002" and the attachment should be an extension to this with a hyphen and two more digits like "-01" and so on for every additional attachment

Comment: If the way I understood your need is correct and you place another question clearly explaining what you want, I can prepare an answer. If somebody else will not answer it and you tag me here, I can help with a piece of code.

Comment: @FaneDuru I have included the sample code to make this question open again. If it doesn't work, I'll post the question again. Thank you in advance

Comment: I am afraid that it is not so simple to reopen a question. I voted to reopen it but more such votes are necessary. So, I would propose you to place another question, showing some code and some other relevant aspects: The text box name keeping the 'invoice', the ones keeping the picture number, the one to change the picture (prev and next), the path of the saved pictures and so on. A link of the example should also be useful, at least for me. I already played on it, in order to make a working solution. Not finalized, because you did not give a sign in a reasonable period of time...

Comment: @FaneDuru fortunately, the question has been opened. You can post the reply please

Comment: OK. I will finalize the code I started preparing using the shared workbook. I will  post an answer soon. And I will also place a link to a transfer site, containing the updated workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way. A text box named "tbOrder" must exist. In it the order/invoice number must be entered (manually or by code). The rest of controls are the one used in your sent testing workbook. Please, copy the next code in the form code module. Only a sub showing the form should exist in a standard module. A new button (`btAttach`) to add attachment has been added and a check box (`chkManyAtt`) where to specify the multiple selection option:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const fPath As String = "C:\test\"
Private photoNo As Long, arrPhoto() As Variant, boolNoEvents As Boolean, prevVal As Long, boolFound As Boolean
Private boolManyAttch As Boolean

Private Sub btAttach_Click()
    If Len(tbOrder.Text) <> 7 Then MsgBox "An invoice number is mandatory in its specific text box (7 digits long)": Exit Sub
    Dim noPhotos As Long, runFunc As String
    
    runFunc = bringPicture(Left(tbOrder.Text, 7), True)
    If Not boolFound Then noPhotos = -1
    
    Dim sourceFile As String, destFile As String, attName As String, strExt As String, i As Long
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = "Please, select the picture to be added as attachment for invoice " & Me.tbOrder.Text & " (" & photoNo & ")"
        .AllowMultiSelect = IIf(boolManyAttch = True, True, False)
        .Filters.Add "Picture Files", "*.jpg", 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
                For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
                    sourceFile = .SelectedItems(i): 'Stop
                    attName = Me.tbOrder.Text & "-" & Format(IIf(noPhotos = -1, 1, photoNo + 1), "00")
                    strExt = "." & Split(sourceFile, ".")(UBound(Split(sourceFile, ".")))
                    destFile = fPath & attName & strExt
                    FileCopy sourceFile, destFile
                    ReDim Preserve arrPhoto(IIf(noPhotos = -1, 0, UBound(arrPhoto) + 1)): noPhotos = 0
                    arrPhoto(UBound(arrPhoto)) = attName & strExt
                    photoNo = photoNo + 1
                Next i
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    Me.TextBox2.Text = photoNo: Me.TextBox2.Enabled = False
    Me.TextBox1.Text = photoNo
End Sub

Private Sub chkManyAtt_Click()
    If Me.chkManyAtt.Value Then
        boolManyAttch = True
    Else
        boolManyAttch = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'Prev button
 Dim currPic As Long

 currPic = Me.TextBox1.Value

 If currPic > 1 Then
    Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(fPath & arrPhoto(currPic - 2))
    boolNoEvents = True                'stop the events when TextBox1 is changed
     Me.TextBox1.Text = currPic - 1
     prevVal = Me.TextBox1.Value
    boolNoEvents = False              'restart events
 End If
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 'Next button
 Dim currPic As Long

    currPic = Me.TextBox1.Value

 If currPic < photoNo Then
    Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(fPath & arrPhoto(currPic))
    boolNoEvents = True
      Me.TextBox1.Text = currPic + 1
      prevVal = Me.TextBox1.Value
    boolNoEvents = False
  Else
    MsgBox "Please, select a valid image number..."
 End If
End Sub

Private Sub tbOrder_Change() 'the textbox where to input the order/invoice nubmer
    Dim firstPict As String
    If Len(tbOrder.Text) >= 7 Then
       photoNo = 0: Erase arrPhoto   'clear the variable keeping the number of found photos and the array keeping them
       firstPict = bringPicture(Left(tbOrder.Text, 7)) 'to make it working even if you paste "Sh-0002-20"
       If firstPict <> "" Then 'determining the first picture to be placed
            With Me.Image1
                .Picture = LoadPicture(fPath & firstPict)
                .PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom
            End With
            boolNoEvents = True      'avoiding the event to be triggeret twice
                Me.TextBox1.Text = 1
                
                With Me.TextBox2
                    .Enabled = True
                    .Text = photoNo
                    .Enabled = False
                End With
            boolNoEvents = False
        Else
            Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(vbNullString) 'clear the picture if no order/invoice have been written in the text box
            Me.TextBox2.Text = "": Me.TextBox1.Text = ""
       End If
    End If
End Sub

Function bringPicture(strName As String, Optional boolAttach As Boolean = False) As String
   Dim PhotoNames As String, arrPh, noPict As Long, firstPict As String, ph As Long
   PhotoNames = Dir(fPath & strName & "*.*") 'find the first photo with the necessary pattern name

   If boolAttach Then
        ReDim arrPhoto(0): photoNo = 0
   Else
        ReDim arrPhoto(photoNo)   'firstly ReDim the array
   End If
   boolFound = False
   Do While PhotoNames <> ""
        boolFound = True
        arrPhoto(photoNo) = PhotoNames: photoNo = photoNo + 1
        ReDim Preserve arrPhoto(photoNo)
        PhotoNames = Dir()
   Loop
   If photoNo > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve arrPhoto(photoNo - 1) 'eliminate the last empty array element
        bringPicture = arrPhoto(0)                 'return the first photo in the array
  End If
  
End Function

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()                     'manually change the picture number
    If Not boolNoEvents Then                        'to not be treggered when changed by code
        If IsNumeric(Me.TextBox1.Value) Then   'to allow only numbers
            If Len(Me.TextBox1.Value) >= Len(CStr(photoNo)) Then 'to allow numbers less or equal with the maximum available
                If CLng(TextBox1.Text) > photoNo Then
                      MsgBox "Select valid image number"
                      boolNoEvents = True
                        Me.TextBox1.Text = prevVal
                      boolNoEvents = False
                Else
                    Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(fPath & arrPhoto(Me.TextBox1.Value - 1))
                    Me.Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom
                End If
                prevVal = Me.TextBox1.Value
            End If
        Else
            Me.TextBox1.Text = ""
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If something not clear enough, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: @Adnan Ahmad Please, download from [here](https://easyupload.io/k23sp2) the working workbook. Send some feedback after testing it. I tried commenting the code lines in a way to be easy understood. I think it is not complicated to apply the solution to your project... But, if something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: @Adnan Ahmad  I feel the need to specify that the workbook is possible to be downloaded for only 7 days...

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. I downloaded the file. I can see it has a text box using which we can recall the photos based on their names. This is the second step. 
The first step is to save the photos using the attachment button and it should give a specific name to the photos based on our invoice number. Does it handle that someway?
Thank you once again

Comment: @Adnan Ahmad No, it doesn't. I only tried making the workbook you shared workable in the way you explained. You have to explain how to be designed the process of attachment saving. Where from the necessary pictures to be taken? How to set the attachment number? Is there a text box keeping it? Should the code ask the user to set it? Should the application automatically increment if for a specific invoice number, each time add 1, in format "00"? I mean 01, 02 ... 99?

Comment: When the userform initialises, a new invoice number is automatically generated. Like "Inv-0004". After entering all other information, the user would click the attachment button to select multiple images (at once or one by one whichever is possible). Then the selected images should be saved in the designated folder with "Inv-0004-01", "Inv-0004-02" and so on (without inverted commas). Let's fix this first and then we can move on to the retrieval step. Thank yo so much

Comment: @Adnan Ahmad Please, test the updated code. Pressing "Add Attachment" button (`btAttach`), it will add a new picture, starting from the maximum existing.

Comment: @Adnan Ahmad Please, download from [here](https://easyupload.io/kdpjax) the updated workbook.

Comment: Woah! @FaneDuru. It just worked the way I wanted. There's one little problem though. When attaching images, upon selecting an image it gives "Runtime error 76: Path not found". Gone into debugging and checked. Path C:\test\ exists and it saves the image with the set name too. But it doesn't allow to add more images as it has run into an error and we have to stop the code there

Comment: @Adnan Ahmad I adapted the code to accept multiple selections when adding attachment(s). The adapted workbook can be downloaded from [here](https://easyupload.io/239mz0). I would also like to remind that we here, when somebody answer our question, vote it up and more important, tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In such a way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the proposed solution works...

Comment: @Adnan Ahmad In order to become an `Application` the code should be adapted to better handle potential errors, to replace a specific picture, to remove it and so on. But this should be your project... If you ask for specific issues we can help. If post another question and tag me (here), if available, i will be glad to help.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and effort. I was a little busy to check timely and respond on time. Accept my apologies. I know VBAs, even I developed this whole project by myself and doing some research. This shipping deal page is just one tiny part of the project. However, this one task was totally new to me. Couldn't find any tutorial video or community Q&A that could help. Let me put this whole code into my project and respond to you on the outcome. Thank you so much

Comment: I pasted your code in the original project file and updated it. And Bravo! it just did what I wanted. That's brilliant. Thank you so so much, Man. You are a saviour. Can't thank you enough. <3